# How can I correct a mistake on my Credit Score?

Tags: canada, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history

I recently just looked at my credit score to try to figure out why I may have been rejected for a credit card. While it is not bad (between 700-725) it is not awesome either. When going through an Equifax report I noticed in the Credit Inquiries to the File section from a bank that I just switched to. They are all one right after another within a few days. I am looking to find out if there is any way that I can get some of them removed as I have read that too many requests can be bad for your score and so I am hoping to improve it by possibly removing these inquiries when there should only be one on there.

The question is can the bank remove the repeat inquiries and if they do will it help?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can dispute a record on your credit report. If you are in Canada you should file a credit dispute form with both [TransUnion](http://www.transunion.ca/ca/personal/creditdisputes_en.page) and [Equifax](http://www.consumer.equifax.ca/dispute-ca/dispute_process/en_ca) (links to the form). In the US there is a third called Experian.

You don't have to explain why you think the records are wrong, just the account and the reason for the dispute. In your case you could say something like 'Credit inquiry duplicate'. The shorter and more precise the better.

They just want accurate info:
'Our goal is to maintain accurate information on your TransUnion credit report.' - TransUnion